# Regex to match everything between <style> and </style> Then Remove with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to remove all  from a string.

```
runReportReq.responseText.replace(/\<style>.*?\</style>/, '')
```

Can anyone show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Notice where syntax highlighting breaks.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the style tags along with the string inside? Or only the string inside the tags? You can do quick syntax checks as described in my answer below.

Comment: It didn't matter to me if I removed the tags or not

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
runReportReq.responseText.replace(/<style>.*?<\/style>/g, '')
```

You can test the validity of the regex syntax here for JavaScript with sample code:
[Regex Tester](http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex)

You can test the regex itself with sample input here for JavaScript:
[RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You've not escaped the right character, try with:

```
/<style>.*?<\/style>/
```

Comment: Can you please help me how to get all styles from body tag? I am trying /<style.*?>(.*\n)*?<\/style>/igm but it also matches script tag and not working properly

Comment: @UmairHamid: Please, ask your own separate question. Comment is not the place for asking questions.

Comment: I cant ask questions :(

Comment: Stackoverflow blocked me due to bad rating

Comment: Would stille miss <style type="text/css">

Answer (score 1):

You need backreferences...

The regex:

```
(\<style\>).+(/\<style\>)
```

Would allow you to replace with backreferences by `$1$2`

So, `<style>asdasd</style>` would result in `<style></style>`

Comment: Thank you, I don't understand regex at all. I'll try this right now

Comment: I presume you need the style tags also removed, right? In that case we do not need backreferences.

Comment: @Everton Agner: "(\<style\>).+(/\<style\>)" would always do a greedy match. So with sample input like "<style>Test1</style>Test2<style>Test3</style>", Test2 also gets removed which is not desirable. Hence you need to add the lazy operator "?". Also you dont need to escape the anchor tags here.

Comment: @Kash Well, I think he messed up with the title: `Regex to match everything between <style> and </style> Then Remove with Javascript`... I thought he tried to remove the content inside the tag, not the whole tag. There would be better ways than regex to do that.

Comment: use ([^<]+) instead of .+. stops it running over the rest of the styles if more than one opening tag is found.

Answer (score 0):

replace returns the processed string, so you have to store the result anywhere

see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: I only posted the bit I was having trouble with, thanks though